# Swift 3 TableView Segue to Multiple Other TableViews

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3

I am building a CTA train tracking app. I have a TableView that is populated with each train line and I am trying to figure out how to go from a click on a TableView cell for one of the train lines to a TableView displaying the parsed JSON data (destination stations and arrival times) for that particular train line.

I am wondering what the best approach for this would be; the simplest seems like I would segue from each clicked cell to a completely different TableView for each train line, but I'm not sure if that is efficient. Otherwise, it seems like I would need to pass the information somehow, such as the JSON feed address, from each clicked cell to the destination TableView. Anybody have any advice? Below is my code:

**Initial screen with all the train lines**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "CTA Train Tracker"
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return trains.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subtitle", for: indexPath)
        let train = trains[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = train.name
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: train.image)
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.        
    }
}
```

**Parsed JSON into TableView**

```
import UIKit

let feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=keygoeshere&mapid=41320&outputType=JSON"

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    class Destinations {
        var destination: String = ""
        var time: String = ""
    }

    var records = [Destinations]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return records.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let destinationRow = records[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = destinationRow.destination
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = destinationRow.time
        return cell
    }

    func parseData() {
        guard let feedURL = URL(string: feed) else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: feedURL)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }
            else {
                if let content = data {                    
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]

                        if let ctattimetable = json["ctatt"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                                for item in estArrivalTime {
                                    if let headingTowards = item["destNm"] as? String,
                                        let arrivalTime = item["arrT"] as? String {
                                        let record = Destinations()
                                        record.destination = headingTowards
                                        record.time = arrivalTime
                                        self.records.append(record)
                                    }
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch { /* Handle error */ }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you've already figured it all out by yourself :).

The classical way is to have a navigation controller with table view controller #1 as its root view controller which shows a list of the train lines. Configure one prototype cell to show general information about a train line. Also, wire up this cell's selection segue to show table view controller #2.

Table view controller #2 could have a prototype cell that shows information about a destination (name and arrival time).

In table view controller #1's `prepare(for:sender:)`, simply follow the comments of the code template: `segue.destinationViewController` will be the table view controller #2 that is about to be shown. Retrieve it as such and configure it with the details about the selected train line (the list of destinations for the selected train line).

Or what do you mean by "I'm not sure if that is efficient"?

Anyways, alternatives you could consider (e.g. depending on the screen size you are targeting) are using a split view controller or a single table view controller that when you tap a train line expands to show the destinations inline.

Hope that brings you on the right track, so to speak :).

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot with figuring out the big picture. Also, thanks for the alternatives to consider, and the train pun :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Also thanks to you for the accept and the upvote. And given the topic, the joke just handed itself on a plate :).